# DateTime Format Exceptions and Computer Date Format

Tags: asp.net, datetime, formatting

My team is building a web app in Asp.Net with C# on SQL Server Express R2. Currently, we're developing in Visual Studio 2010 with the database hosted on a separate server. We're running the app on the development server of our home computers.

If I change my home computer date format to **d/M/yyyy** and the date format I want in **M/d/yyyy** for my code, I get errors. It accepts dates up to the 12th day of the month because it assumes the day field is actually the month field. After that, I get a giant format exception when I try to convert the string to a DateTime. This is a huge problem and our client wants the date format in M/d/yyyy.

I've tried everything I can think of!

**Changing the web.config doesn't work:**

```
<globalization culture="auto:en-US" uiCulture="auto:en" />
```

**Using a format when converting:**

```
String strDate = myDate.ToString("M/d/yyyy")
```

**Using a format and culture info when converting:**

```
DateTime myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate, new CultureInfo("en-CA"));
```

None of this works! We're in a real pinch right now, I'd appreciate any information on the matter. At the moment, I can only hope when we run it on the actual server, it will run correctly if the server's date is formatted properly.

Comment: What is the date format of your regional settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DateTime.ParseExact("12/15/2009", "M/d/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-CA"));
```

This should work

Comment: Can you give me any other info on why it was doing this in the first place? Why it was using my computer's date format?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know, I've encountered this in the past; Datetime conversion is always an issue... As far as I can gather from the MSDN documentation though Convert.ToDateTime does not work even though it should, I've found the best is to use the parseexact with your dateformat and you can be guaranteed that that will work

Comment: Here is one thing that looks to be one of the issues, execute the following code: CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-CA");
                string patternShort = ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
                string patternLong = ci.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern; With my code the shortdate is actually what my machine is set to and not M/d/yyyy, that might be why it's causing the error, although I am not entirely sure what format Convert uses.

Comment: OK thanks. One last question, how can I include the time in the format "hh:mm tt"? Is that possible?

Comment: yeah sure, you would just replace the second string with whatever date format you are going to pass it in: i.e. DateTime.ParseExact("12/15/2009 10:50 pm", "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", new CultureInfo("en-CA")). Just remember though, because you are using parse exact, the datetime you are passing should include every detail specified in the string

Comment: Thanks a lot! Super helpful :) I was getting errors converting the time.